# why variable computed after called in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I tried my program https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RhCRxZkEQUqbC2gpiRtKnA

My program:

```
val m = Map((1, "abc"), (2, "aaa"), (4, "aaaaaa"), (3, "a"), (5, "78"))
var mm :Map[Int, String] = Map.empty

val r = m.filterKeys { k =>
  if(k>3) true else {
    println(k)
    mm += (k -> m(k))
    false
  }
}

println("end of program", mm)

r // last line
```

The output is

```
(end of program,Map())
1
2
3
```

If last line `r` removed, the output is

```
(end of program,Map())
```

Why? any hints welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API [documentation for Map.filterKeys](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#filterKeys(p:K=%3EBoolean):scala.collection.Map[K,V]) says:

> @returns an immutable map consisting only of those key value pairs of this map where the key satisfies the predicate p. The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements.

This means that `filterKeys` does not start the evaluation eagerly, but instead constructs a lazy view that hides some of the keys. The predicate is not evaluated until you actually try to access the key, or, in this case, until you iterate through the map.

The iteration is triggered by the `toString` method.
The `toString` method on `r` is invoked by the REPL (in this case, by Scastie) as soon as you write `r`, because it has to produce a string representation of the result.

Note that nothing is printed if you run the same program as a script: when run as a script, no `toString` is invoked on intermediate results, therefore there is no need to iterate through the map, and therefore the `toString` is not invoked.

Comment: thanks. I read the API doc, but I cannot understand. Does `wraps the original map without copying any elements` mean that `filterKeys` is lazily evaluated?

Comment: @BAE since it does not set up any data structure that copies the elements, it would make no sense to evaluate the predicate eagerly, because you would have no data structure to store the results. Therefore, the only possibility is that the filtering predicate is evaluated lazily.

Comment: I still have some questions: 1, any other operations are lazy? 2, when the filtering predicate starts evaluation, does this need another thread; 3, I have a question here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337714/weird-async-multiple-phenomenon-in-my-scala-codes, it seems that it needs another thread? and why it seems that it is evaluated lazily more than once. I may be wrong.

Comment: @BAE 1. Whole bunch of operations are lazy. You usually have to look into the API, sometimes just thinking what could be more efficient could give you a clue. But there is no general rule, as far as I can tell. Some operations are sometimes "unexpectedly lazy". 2. Definitely not, why should it? 3. I don't know, I haven't looked at it. I suggest you try to get the questions solved one by one, otherwise it's too much multi-tasking. If the other question isn't answered, then maybe you should provide further details, and comment if something is unclear about the answers.